# How to display data made by cobs spline package as ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
wt1 <- cobs(x, y, constraint= "increase", lambda = 1, pointwise = con)
```

## to make quadratic B-spline

`plot(wt1)` works fine

[image]

But if I use ggplot2, error message below comes to me

> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by
>   `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class cobs

so i extracted data from cobs using `predict(wt1)` but it only contains specific points (x,y), not splined curve.
[image]

how can I make ggplot2 object using splined smooth line generated by cobs package?

Comment: I never worked with cobs, but with the function `coef` you can extract the coefficients of the spline from `wt1`

Answer (score 2):

You make a wrong statement in the question, `predict` doesn't return points `x` and `y`, it returns a two column matrix with the fitted values in the second column.
I will use the data created in the first example of `help('cobs')`.

```
library(cobs)

set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

x <- seq(-1, 3, , 150)
y <- (f.true <- pnorm(2*x)) + rnorm(150)/10
con <- rbind(c( 1,min(x),0), # f(min(x)) >= 0
             c(-1,max(x),1), # f(max(x)) <= 1
             c(0,  0,   0.5))# f(0)      = 0.5
```

Now get the fitted values and put `x`, `y` and `fit` in a dataframe, so that `ggplot` doesn't complain.

```
wt1 <- cobs(x,y, constraint= "increase", lambda = 1, pointwise = con)

fit <- predict(wt1, x)[, 'fit']
df1 <- data.frame(x, y, fit)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit), colour = 'red')
```

[image]